# Understanding an algorithm that searches for a maximum-sum subsequence

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

I am struggling with an algorithm that solves the [PE Problem #149](https://projecteuler.net/problem=149). This algorithm, already fully programmed, can be found [here](http://rafal.io/posts/project-euler-149-maximumsum-subsequence.html).

Within this particular algorithm, I do not understand why the programmer has written code for a **diagonal 2** direction and **anti-diagonal 2** direction. Is this necessary from a programming point of view? I can't think of any mathematical reason!

Why does it not suffice to look **only** in the (1) horizontal, (2) vertical, (3) diagonal and (4) anti-diagonal directions?? We are dealing with a nxn matrix (square) in the end...

Let me know your thoughts on this. In the meanwhile I'm waiting for reply from the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is just an implementation detail. It still looks only in 4 directions. It is necessary because a diagonal can either end in the last row and some column or in the last column and some row.

Comment: That would be necessary in the case of a mxn matrix, but what we are dealing with is a square matrix, therefore, your last row/column is always the same. For that reason, I do not understand the need.

Am I thinking wrong? If so, could you please give me a small example I can try to reason on. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: @Hotnuto Let's assume that the matrix is [[1, 2], [3, 4]]. One diagonal  ends in element 3(last row, first column), one ends in element 2(last column, first row). So they are in different groups here(I mean that one of them ends in the last column but not the last row and vice versa).

Comment: Following your comment, I'd get this: [[1 2*] [3* 4]] and [[1 2*] [3* 4]] . In which the * mark the element that is in inside of a diagonal group.

So in the end, it is the same result, right? O_o